# MERN blog - how to display posts latest first?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

I want to be able to display the newest blog posts first, at the moment when a user adds a post the latest post adds below the previous one - I want the opposite to happen so the newest post is the first post.

```
import Header from "../../components/header/Header";
import Posts from "../../components/posts/Posts";
import Sidebar from "../../components/sidebar/Sidebar";
import "./home.css";
import axios from "axios";
import { useLocation } from "react-router";

export default function Home() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const { search } = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPosts = async () => {
      const res = await axios.get("/posts" + search);
      setPosts(res.data);
    };
    fetchPosts();
  }, [search]);
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <div className="home">
        <Posts posts={posts} />
        <Sidebar />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally sorted data should be served from API response. Your API call would look something like this - `/posted?orderBy=createdAt`.

If you want to achieve this from client side, you may use array `reverse()`
method like this - `setPosts(res.data.reverse());`